# Not retriving JSON data in Ajax call(Reslet web service)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

My AJAX send data in JSon format to Reslet web service.
Service execute successfully but not returning data in AJAX success method.

My AJAX call:

```
var jsonToBeSend=new Object();

jsonToBeSend["user"] ="chaitanya@gmail.com";
jsonToBeSend["pass"] ="123";
j.ajax({                
  url: "http://1.255.255.112:8080/MyProject/WebService/Login/LoginWebService", 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'application/json', 
  data: JSON.stringify(jsonToBeSend),
  success: function(data) { 
    alert("success: "+data);
  },
  error:function(data) { 
    alert("error: "+data);
  }
});
```

My Java code:

```
@Post
public JSONObject authenticateUser(Representation entity) throws JSONException {
    TnEUtility.loggerMessage(logger, "authenticateUser","Start");
    JSONObject toBeSentJSONObject=new JSONObject();
    try{
        toBeSentJSONObject.put("Status", "Success");
        toBeSentJSONObject.put("Message",message);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        toBeSentJSONObject.put("Status","Error");
        TnEUtility.loggerErrorMessage(logger,"Login Web Service",e);
    }
    TnEUtility.loggerMessage(logger, "authenticateUser","Ende");
    return toBeSentJSONObject;
}
js/jquery-1.7.2.js
```

This java code gets the call and executes, but AJAX error occurs. My HTML file which contain AJAX call is outside of myProject which has web service. But when I make this call from Poster plugin of firefox, output getting in that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use data.KeyName, a KeyName is a value in JSON format. for example

```
{"User":"chaitanya@gmail.com","Password":"123"}
```

so you could get User value like this

```
data.User; 
data.Password
```

In your code you could change

```
success: function(data) { 
                            alert("success: "+data.User);
                        },
```